# Pandas dataframe append function adding empty columns with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following piece of code:

```
graphdata = pd.DataFrame(columns=['MaturityGroup','SumOfNetAssetPercent'] )
print(graphdata.dtypes)
graphdata["SumOfNetAssetPercent"] = graphdata["SumOfNetAssetPercent"].astype(float)
print(graphdata.dtypes)
graphdata.info()
graphdata = graphdata.append([['Remainder', filterdata[FilterRemainder]['NetAssetPercent'].sum()]
                          , ['<1 Yr', filterdata[Filter0to1Year]['NetAssetPercent'].sum()]
                          , ['1 to <3 Yrs', filterdata[Filter1to3Year]['NetAssetPercent'].sum()]
                          , ['3 to <5 Yrs', filterdata[Filter3to5Year]['NetAssetPercent'].sum()]
                          , ['5 Yrs & Above', filterdata[Filter5YrNAbove]['NetAssetPercent'].sum()]]
                            , ignore_index=True)

print(graphdata)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
MaturityGroup           object
SumOfNetAssetPercent    object
dtype: object
MaturityGroup            object
SumOfNetAssetPercent    float64
dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                --------------  -----  
 0   MaturityGroup         0 non-null      object 
 1   SumOfNetAssetPercent  0 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes
  MaturityGroup  SumOfNetAssetPercent              0          1
0           NaN                   NaN      Remainder   5.370009
1           NaN                   NaN          <1 Yr   7.295347
2           NaN                   NaN    1 to <3 Yrs  39.340446
3           NaN                   NaN    3 to <5 Yrs  12.524880
4           NaN                   NaN  5 Yrs & Above  35.472455
```

My question is, **why 'append' adds two additional empty NaN column to my empty dataframe?**

Comment: Can you please share a sample of `filterdata` also?

Comment: @MayankPorwal The problem isn't with filter data, coz when im using ```pd.DataFrame``` instead of ```graphdata.append``` it works fine with data being saved to the 2 defined columns with no additional ones being created.. However i need to run the code in a loop, hence wanted to keep appending to existing dataframe.

Comment: Another thing to mention is if the ```graphdata``` dataframe already has any existing data then ```graphdata.append``` works perfectly. It is only with the first time when it is empty the problem is arising.

Answer (score 3):

The two rows are getting added because you are appending rows that don't  have the same column names as the original dataframe.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b"])
print(df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

Create a datarame to append but without column names.

```
df_other = pd.DataFrame([["remainder", 5.3], ["more", 2.2], ["some", 66]])
print(df_other)
          0     1
0  remainder   5.3
1       more   2.2
2       some  66.0
```

Now append them...

```
df = df.append(df_other)
print(df)
     a    b          0     1
0  NaN  NaN  remainder   5.3
1  NaN  NaN       more   2.2
2  NaN  NaN       some  66.0
```

Now change the appending dataframe to include columns.

```
df_other = pd.DataFrame(
    [["remainder", 5.3], ["more", 2.2], ["some", 66]], columns=["a", "b"]
)
print(df_other)
          a     b
0  remainder   5.3
1       more   2.2
2       some  66.0
```

And the result is.

```
df = df.append(df_other)
print(df)
           a     b
0  remainder   5.3
1       more   2.2
2       some  66.0
```